# Using graphics card with no video output?

Tags: graphics-card, gaming, rendering

I've been looking into upgrading my graphics card for a while now, and during my searches I've noticed a couple of them that don't have any sort of video output other than power and PCI. I was wondering if it would be possible to install a graphics card such as an Nvidia Tesla M2070 so that it renders games and whatever I do on my computer, and outputs it through my current ports, which are on my current graphics card, as there is no built in gpu on my motherboard. I'm curious about this because a lot of these cards, while cheap, have incredibly high memories and seem superior to other cards in the same price range.

Comment: Tesla is not for gaming.  Really not sure what you are asking about.

Comment: Like @SiXandSeven8ths said, Tesla is not for gaming, not even video output. It's for GPU Computing where large memory is useful. It won't have anywhere near the graphics performance of a similarly priced GPU but it will by far outpace any normal GPU when it comes to CUDA/OpenCL.